# Adding an array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and I want to create a new column and add arrays to this each row of this new column. I know to do this I have to change the datatype of the column to 'object' I tried the following but it doesn;t work,

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]})
df['b'] = np.nan
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(object)
df.loc[0,'b'] = [[1,2,4,5]]
```

The error is

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

However, it works if I convert the datatype of the whole dataframe into 'object':

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]})
df['b'] = np.nan
df = df.astype(object)
df.loc[0,'b'] = [[1,2,4,5]]
```

So my question is: why do I have to change the datatype of whole DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
In [12]: df.at[0,'b'] = [1,2,4,5]

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   a             b
0  1  [1, 2, 4, 5]
1  2           NaN
2  3           NaN
3  4           NaN
```

PS be aware that as soon as you put non scalar value in any cells - the corresponding column's dtype will be changed to `object` in order to be able to contain non-scalar values:

```
In [14]: df.dtypes
Out[14]:
a     int64
b    object
dtype: object
```

PPS generally it's a bad idea to store non-scalar values in cells, because the vast majority of Pandas/Numpy methods will not work properly with such data.

Comment: This is the first time I stumble upon `.at`, why not `loc`?

Comment: @iDrwish, `.at` and `.iat` are designed for working with __single__ cells, where `.loc` and `.iloc` are more complicated and have more logic for aligning data, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my original example why do I need to change the data type of whole dataframe, instead of just the column?

Comment: @lizardfireman, using `.at` - you don't need to cast the whole DF to `object` dtype - see the output of `df.dtypes` in my answer. In regards to "why `df.loc[0,'b'] = [[...]]` works when the whole DF is casted to `object` dtype" - i don't know...

Comment: +1, Performance note: `at` and `iat` (both very much underused) are *much* more efficient than `.loc` based equivalents to access scalars.